Is there a way to create a variable that will be accessible by all futures from ProcessPoolExecutor?
I'm writing a simple brute force function with a ProcessPoolExecutor. The task is to find matching hashes of 8-digit passwords.
And I noticed a problem that if all given passwords are found, the function will be still looping.
I tried to implement a global counter variable, but as I soon realized, it is not shared between futures. Is there any way to create a counter or maybe something else that all processes will be aware of to cut the execution time?
Here is my executor manager:
def brute_force_password() -> None:
    futures = []

    with ProcessPoolExecutor(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as executor:

        for interval in range(len(PASSWORDS_TO_BRUTE_FORCE)):
            futures.append(
                executor.submit(
                    check_password_in_interval,
                    interval * 1_000_0000,
                    (interval + 1) * 1_000_0000
                )
            )

    wait(futures)

And loop-checking function:
def check_password_in_interval(start: int, end: int) -> None:
    for guess in range(start, end):
        guess = f"{guess:08d}"
        hashed_guess = sha256_hash_str(guess)

        if hashed_guess in PASSWORDS_TO_BRUTE_FORCE:
            index = PASSWORDS_TO_BRUTE_FORCE.index(hashed_guess)
            HACKED_PASSWORDS[index] = guess

            print(f"{hashed_guess} is {guess}.")

I'll appreciate your time and help!
What I tried: global and environment variables

you can try and use multiprocessing which allows you to share values across processes:
import multiprocessing
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, wait
from ctypes import c_int

def brute_force_password(passwords_found: multiprocessing.Value) -> None:
    futures = []
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as executor:
        for interval in range(len(PASSWORDS_TO_BRUTE_FORCE)):
            futures.append(
                executor.submit(
                    check_password_in_interval,
                    interval * 1_000_0000,
                    (interval + 1) * 1_000_0000,
                    passwords_found
                )
            )
        wait(futures)

def check_password_in_interval(start: int, end: int, passwords_found: multiprocessing.Value) -> None:
    for guess in range(start, end):
        guess = f"{guess:08d}"
        hashed_guess = sha256_hash_str(guess)
        if hashed_guess in PASSWORDS_TO_BRUTE_FORCE:
            with passwords_found.get_lock():
                index = PASSWORDS_TO_BRUTE_FORCE.index(hashed_guess)
                HACKED_PASSWORDS[index] = guess
                passwords_found.value += 1
                print(f"{hashed_guess} is {guess}.")
                if passwords_found.value == len(PASSWORDS_TO_BRUTE_FORCE):
                    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    passwords_found = multiprocessing.Value(c_int, 0)
    brute_force_password(passwords_found)

